# Отследить KeyPress из класса наследника TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, события

Создал класс у которого родитель TabPage (проект winforms), как мне отслеживать нажатие клавиш из класса?

Comment: А как вы у самого TabPage отслеживали?

Comment: @АндрейNOP в том то и вопрос как програмно OnKeyPress сделать

Comment: Ну вы пробовали набрать "override OnKeyPress"? Или подписаться на событие "KeyPress" в коде?